# How to sort a text containing numbers by numbers' values?

Tags: pega

I have got a repeat layout with the several columns. One of them prints data as "123 days", so it is Text.
When I try to order rows by the column, I get something like: "121 days", "122 days", "123 days", "13 days", "124 days".

A property of the column is contained in the Data Base as Integer, but there is an activity, which converts it into Text adding "days".
I suppose that the solution of the issue is utilizing Number despite of Text, but displaying "days" is a business requirement and I am
not able to just throw it out.

Are there any workarounds to display "days" and to order the column as Number?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a workaround. You need to create your own `Control` rule to display Number + "days".

Don't append days through the activity. Keep numbers as it is. You must be using `Text Input` control to display the property.

Create you own `control`. Uncheck the `Auto-Generated?` check box from `HTML` tab.

In the code part write this.

```
<%= tools.getActiveValue() %> days
```

Thats it.